# Can I justify text with Typeface.js? How does the rendering compare with Cufon?

Tags: cufon, typeface.js

I'd be using Cufon, but I can't justify the text. I've read that Typeface.js works similarly to Cufon, (renders its own text so it looks good in Windows browsers that don't provide anti-aliasing) so I'd like to know how the rendering quality compares (Cufon's is great) and if you can justify text--no mention  that you can or can't on the Typeface.js homesite that I could find... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you know it already but there is also [Google Font](http://code.google.com/apis/webfonts/) that does the same thing as Cufon and Typeface, except there is a limited choice of fonts (you cannot upload whichever you like). However, it does support "justify" + it's clean and fast.

Comment: I checked that out, and Typekit and others like it. Unfortunately, those services depend on the browser's rendering engine to anti-alias the text, so it still jagged. The main reason I'm interested in type replacement is for smoothly rendered text which is why I'm currently using sIFR. But sIFR is tricky to make work with js animations...